# How to get access to Validation.Errors.Count?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, binding

I follow an example on CodeProject: ["*Automatically validating business entities in WPF using custom binding and attributes*"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39198/Automatically-validating-business-entities-in-WPF) and I want to add a button which is enabled when there are no errors.

I have this line on my MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Button Height="23" Margin="38,63,0,0" Name="button1"
         IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).Count}" />
```

I'll use a converter, but I need to know the type of the input and return a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas,

In the example in the above link, there is a model object with an Error property that we can use.

I changed it a bit so that we have Error not empty if any field in error - there is only one field.

The class now raises some events so that there can have some "real time" modification to the IsEnabled  state of the button, when there is an error added/removed to the form :

```
public class User : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Name"];
        }
    }
```

Then the binding on the button is only :

```
    <Button 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Error, 
                            Converter={StaticResource stringToBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Provided that the converter exists :

```
class StringToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        String s = value as String;
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I tested, it works, tell me if any problem

Answer (score 0):

make a property similar to where if the count is 0, set false:

```
    private bool _enableButton;

    public bool ButtonEnabled
    {
        get { return _enableButton; }
        set { _enableButton= value; }
    }
```

Somewhere in your controller code, set:

```
 ButtonEnabled = (items.Count == 0) ? false : true;
```

then in your xaml code, you shouldn't need a converter just bind it appropriately.

p.s. please use more meaningful names then what I have in my example